# How to get LaTeX table from latex() in Hmisc to align columns

Tags: r, latex

I have some problems getting the align to work in my latex table, here's an example:

```
library(Hmisc)
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(round(runif(6*3)*10, 2), ncol=6)
x[1, 2] <- -round(x[1, 2], 0)
x[3, 3] <- -round(x[1, 2], 1)
x[3, 5] <- round(x[1, 2], 1)

ci1 <- apply(x[,2:3], 1, FUN=function(x){
        ret <- paste(min(x), "-", max(x))
        return(ret)
})
ci2 <- apply(x[,5:6], 1, FUN=function(x){
        ret <- paste(min(x), "-", max(x))
        return(ret)
})

x <- cbind(x[,1], ci1, x[,4], ci2)
colnames(x) <- c("A", "interval", "B", "interval")
rownames(x) <- sapply(letters[1:3], FUN=function(x){ return(paste("Var_", x, sep=""))})

latex(x, file="", align="rcrc", rowlabel.just="r", 
      cgroup = c("First", "Second"), 
      n.cgroup = c(2, 2),
      rgroup=c("Grup A and B", "Group C"), 
      n.rgroup=c(2, NROW(x) - 2), 
      ctable=T)
```

This produces:

```
% latex.default(x, file = "", align = "rcrc", rowlabel.just = "r",      cgroup = c("First", "Second"), n.cgroup = c(2, 2), rgroup = c("Grup A and B",          "Group C"), n.rgroup = c(2, NROW(x) - 2), ctable = T) 
%
\ctable[ label=x, pos=!tbp, ]{rllcll} {} {\FL\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries x}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries First}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Second}
\NN \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{interval}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{B}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{interval}\NN
\ML
{\bfseries Grup A and B}&&&&&\NN
Var_a&2.66&-9 - 9.45&&0.62&4.98 - 6.87\NN
Var_b&3.72&2.02 - 6.61&&2.06&3.84 - 7.18\NN
\ML
{\bfseries Group C}&&&&&\NN
Var_c&5.73&8.98 - 9&&1.77&-9 - 9.92\NN
\LL
}
```

The error is here:

```
\ctable[ label=x, pos=!tbp, ]{rllcll}
```

I want **rllcll** to be **rrccrc** but it doesn't do that. I have tried all possible alternatives for the aling and halign parameter. It's a little annoying to be doing this by hand...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the way to do it. The main changes to the code is to use `col.just = c('r', 'c', 'r', 'c')` instead of `align`. Moreover, your row names have underscores, which will cause `latex` to throw an error. So use `latexTranslate` to escape your underscores and prevent error

```
latex(x, file="", col.just = strsplit("rcrc", "")[[1]], rowlabel.just="r", 
  cgroup = c("First", "Second"), n.cgroup = c(2, 2),
  rgroup = c("Grup A and B", "Group C"), n.rgroup=c(2, NROW(x) - 2), 
  booktabs = T, rowname = latexTranslate(rownames(x)))
```

[image]

Comment: i pasted the wrong code (in fact the original one used by the OP. i have corrected it now. the latex code shows `\begin{tabular}{rrccrc}`

Comment: The formatting of the numbers is still wrong. Note for instance the wrong minus sign and the spacing. I’m also pretty certain that the “x” (and possibly the group names) should be formatted as variable names.

Comment: well. i will leave it to the OP to specify clearly what he wants. from the post, it appears that he wants to replace `{rllcll}` with `{rrccrc}`, which is what this accomplishes. so unless the OP clarifies what he wants, we can all make our own guesses.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe col.just was so hard to find. I went through the manual once again: "... format.df (e.g., col.just and other formatting options like dec, rdec, and cdec)". Unbelievable, tables are after all one of the main purpose with LaTeX in R and wanting to align them doesn't seem like an uncommon thing to do... Regarding the "x" you just need to specify the rowlabel="My variables" and I actually had the _ on purpose but in my real script I use the latextTranslate() as you suggest on both rows and columns. And thanks for the booktabs=T tip, it looks much nicer.

Comment: I landed here with a similar problem to the OP. I don't understand this. If `align` isn't the correct answer, then what is the purpose of it? Anyone reading the document would think `align` was the correct argument. I see help(latex) talks about `col.just` in the context of passing arguments to `format.df`, but this is not something most people would think of doing.

Comment: `align` is an argument used with `latexTabular` and it does exactly the same as `col.just` for `latex`. I agree it is inconsistent and a poor design choice.

Comment: @Ramnath Yes, I realised that afterwards, but I suspect most people would be using `latex` anyway. Also, the connection of `latex` to the `format.df` function is not clear.

Comment: @Faheem You are absolutely correct. The `latex` function in `Hmisc` is very powerful, but poorly designed IMHO.